# Mongoengine query with date range

Tags: python, flask, flask-mongoengine

I'm trying to retrieve data from mongodb via mongoengine within a specified time span. Below is the db model used.

```
class DeviationReport(db.Document):
    meta = {'collection': 'DeviationReport'}
    created_at = db.DateTimeField()
    date = db.DateTimeField()
    author = db.StringField()
    read_by = db.ListField(default=[])
    prod_line = db.ReferenceField(ProductionLine)
    product = db.ReferenceField(Product)
    description = db.StringField()
```

What I've tried is the code below. It does however not return any results. I've used a similar approach when I've needed to build dynamic queries depending on user input.

```
kwargs = {}
start = datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 11)
end = datetime.datetime(2019, 03, 13)
kwargs['created_at'] = { '$lt': end, '$gt': start }
DeviationReport.objects(**kwargs)
```

I've obviously made sure that there are objects within the date range, and I've read other similar posts where the query below has been successfully used. How do I get my query to return everything between 'start' and 'end', or how do I rewrite it to do as I wish?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I worked around/solved the problem by first getting my results sans date filtering using **kwargs and then filtered that using Q. It may not be optimal, but it works for what I need it to do.

```
reports = DeviationReport.objects(**kwargs)
reports = reports.filter((Q(date__gte=start) & Q(date__lte=end)))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of ways to achieve your query, adjust the collection and params accordingly using the example below:

```py
date_to = datetime.datetime.utcnow() # The end date
date_from = date_to - datetime.timedelta(days=120) # The start date

query_a = Application.objects(category="rest_api").filter(
    date_created__gte=date_from, 
    date_created__lte=date_to
)

query_b = Application.objects(
    date_created__gte=date_from, 
    date_created__lte=date_to
).filter(category="rest_api")

query = {"category": "rest_api"}

query_c = Application.objects(
    date_created__gte=date_from,
    date_created__lte=date_to,
    **query
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Querying with Q as suggested above did not work for me, but a [raw query](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#raw-queries) did:

```
raw_query = {'date': {'$gte': start, '$lt': end}}
reports = DeviationReport.objects(__raw__=raw_query)
```